# Testing WPF simple application on multiple web browsers

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, silverlight

I'm newbie in WPF/Silverlight world. In the first step , I developed a "Hello world" application and simply run it but the problem is application successfully run only on Internet explorer. When I changed my browser like chrome or firefox etc, application pop up a Save window which means browser unable to understand the filetype. I want to know any plugin required to smothly run my WPF project on different web browsers.

Comment: Im facing problems in WPF on different browsers....

Comment: After brain storming on WPF browsers issues, finally i found the solution and successfully run my WPF hello world app on firefox browser...please follow thius procedure: copy "npwpf.dll"(if you have MS framework 3.5 or above, you can find this easily) or download) then put this file in plugins folder C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\plugins....and also paste in c:\users\yourname\AppData\Roaming. if you not able to find plugins folder then make this folder and simply paste said file......it'll work

Answer (score 1):

IMO, You are referring to Silverlight and not WPF
WPF Applications are Desktop Applications and they are not made for Browsers.

And Silverlight is cross-platform, across browsers.

You can download and install the plugin from here, 
http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/Get-Started/Install/Default.aspx

Comment: well searching on my WPF solution on internet, firefox browser do support WPF applications but need to install some plugin, so here is my problem arise failed badly to get any tested plugin....

Comment: Maybe you are searching for this, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716877.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Silverlight, not 100% sure tough

Answer (score 0):

WPF browser based application can run in the IE and firefox web browser. One can use silverlight for implementing the WPf browser based application. But silverlight is the small subset of WPF framework. The machine running the WPF web browseer based application must be installed with the .Net runtime environment. WPF web browser based application ideally used for the intranet usages.

Comment: literally i fed up searching firefox solution to run my WPF application, can any one give me firefox plugin link ....

Comment: Following link may be helpful to you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716877.aspx